# How do I access a specific element of a supersorted array?

Tags: array, plugin-supersort

Let's say we have this setup:

```
{% set myArray = [9,3,5,7,2,1] %}
{% set mySortedArray = myArray | supersort() %}
```

It gives us:

```
myArray = array(6) {
    [0]=int(9)
    [1]=int(3)
    [2]=int(5)
    [3]=int(7)
    [4]=int(2)
    [5]=int(1)
}

mySortedArray = array(6) {
    [5]=int(1)
    [4]=int(2)
    [1]=int(3)
    [2]=int(5)
    [3]=int(7)
    [0]=int(9)
}
```

How can I access say the second element of `mySortedArray`?

If I do `{{ mySortedArray[2] }}` I get `5`, but I want the `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `mySortedArray` through the [`| values` filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#values), it will reset the keys:

```
{% set mySortedArray = myArray | supersort | values %}
```

```
mySortedArray = array(6) {
    [0]=int(1)
    [1]=int(2)
    [2]=int(3)
    [3]=int(5)
    [4]=int(7)
    [5]=int(9)
}
```

Comment: Gee, I had scrutinised all the Twig filters but forgotten about Craft's! Thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Jalen's answer, if you want to preserve your array keys, you can use this:

```
{% set sortedArrayKeys = mySortedArray | keys %}
```

and then access any item with

```
mySortedArray[sortedArrayKeys[index]]
```